# How to find third friday of the Month in Java 8?

Tags: date, time, calendar, java-8

I tried searching the question, but no answer explains the Java 8 way of doing this. Can any body help me out with the same?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The **THIRD** Friday of December 2016 must be:

```
LocalDate d = LocalDate.now();
d = d.with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(3, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
System.out.println(d); // 2016-12-16
```